# Perl script executing mysql commands?

Tags: mysql, perl

I'm new to Perl and was attempting to write a script on a RHEL box that will auto-configure a vanilla DB for new sites we create on our host.  I already have the connect statement working and I'm able to connect and create a DB from the script (Used $dbh->do( qq(CREATE DATABASE $dbcreate) ); Is this the best way???), but I have a couple that I haven't been able to figure out how to make them work.

These are the mysql commands which I'm having issues with.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

```
$dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$db:$host", $user, $pass);
$dbh->do( qq(CREATE DATABASE $dbcreate) );
$dbh->do(qq(GRANT SELECT , INSERT , UPDATE , DELETE , CREATE , DROP , INDEX , ALTER , CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES , CREATE VIEW , SHOW VIEW , CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, EXECUTE ON `$dbcreate` . * TO 'moodle'@'%'`) );
$dbh->do( qq(FLUSH PRIVILEGES) );
$dbh->do( qq($dbcreate < MySQL_pristine.sql) );
$dbh->do( qq(USE $dbcreate) );
$dbh->do( qq(UPDATE md1_label SET content = REPLACE( content, "pristine", "$dbcreate")) );
$dbh->do( qq(UPDATE md1_label SET contents = REPLACE( contents, "pristine", "$dbcreate")) );
$dbh->do( qq(UPDATE md1_label SET questiontext = REPLACE( questiontext, "pristine", "$dbcreate")) );

DBD::mysql::db do failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GRANT SELECT , INSERT , UPDATE , DELETE , CREATE , DROP , INDEX ,�' at line 1 at create-auto-db.pl line 52.
DBD::mysql::db do failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'test3 < MySQL_pristine.sql' at line 1 at create-auto-db.pl line 54.
DBD::mysql::db do failed: Table 'test3.md1_label' doesn't exist at create-auto-db.pl line 56.
DBD::mysql::db do failed: Table 'test3.md1_label' doesn't exist at create-auto-db.pl line 57.
DBD::mysql::db do failed: Table 'test3.md1_label' doesn't exist at create-auto-db.pl line 58.
```

Comment: If you're using DBI, why are you also trying to work interactively with the mysql shell?  The first half of your question deals with Perl, the second half deals with redirecting a file to the command line tool 'mysql'.  There's no Perl in your example code.  Also, you haven't explained what issues you're having.  Should we guess?

Comment: All of these statements work just fine from `DBI`, and can be executed from `$dbh->do()`. If you're getting error messages, post them, and a little more of the Perl. There are a few risks in the single statement you posted, but not much that we can assist with in the absence of any context. One likely issue is your use of `@` which might be interpolated if you quote the string wrongly (i.e., with `qq{}` rather than `q{}`).

Comment: @morungos I've edited my post to include the code i've tried along with the errors below.  I think you're right about the @ symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue you've encountered is interpolation of strings with containing an at-sign. If you have something like `qq{Here is my email: test@hotmail.com}` - this fails because it tries to put a list variable `@hotmail`, which doesn't exist. Either use a backslash to escape it (i.e., `qq{Here is my email: test\@hotmail.com}`), or if you don't need to interpolate any variables, use the non-interpolating quote `q{...}`.

Having said that, you need to be a little careful with some of these statements. You're putting variable values into these SQL statements, and that is a risk for SQL injection attacks. I'd use `$dbh->quote($dbcreate)` to get a string version, and `$dbh->quote_identifier($dbcreate)` to get an identifier version of the value of `$dbcreate`, and embed those values in. This is much safer, as it will avoid somebody doing a Bobby Tables on you and giving you a database name like: `db'; DROP TABLE mysql.user; ';` or similar. DBI provides both string and identifier quoting, so you can get the right kinds of quoting as needed. For example:

```
my $quoted_id_dbcreate = $dbh->quote_identifier($dbcreate);
$dbh->do( qq(USE $quoted_id_dbcreate) );
```

Placeholders are usually better, but some of these admin statements probably won't support them, so using proper quoting to inject the values is likely to be necessary.

Comment: Thank you, this is now working as intended!  I'm not to worried about any kind of injections because this will be ran from the command line in a non-web accessible directory and only root can rwx the file.  I'm sure my code isn't done the best, but it gets the job done.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Two things stand out to me.

```
$dbh->do(qq(GRANT SELECT , INSERT , (snip), EXECUTE ON '$dbcreate' . * TO 'moodle'@'%'`) );
```

...you've got a trailing backtick that you probably don't intend.

```
$dbcreate < MySQL_pristine.sql
```

...isn't quite what you want. I think you're trying to do is to read that file in Perl, and iterate over each contained SQL statement, calling "$dbh->do()" against it. If you're very lucky, you have one line per statement in that .sql file.